# (search) form without redirect or submit handler

Tags: forms, search

Use case:
Search field e.g. in the header, that leads to a url with GET query string.

The usual flow of forms built with Drupal 7 form API is like this:

- User visits a page with the form.
- User submits, $_POST or $_GET
- Validate + submit handlers are called
- Redirect to a new page.

What i would like instead:

- User visits page with the form, that was built with form API.
- User submits, resulting in a $_GET request, e.g. example.com/search?query=foo+bar.
- The page example.com/search?query=foo+bar is served, without thinking about form API.

So, I want to use form API to build the form HTML (cause it's convenient), but not any submit magic.

Ideas?
Maybe I could find an example in existing modules, but I am looking for a "big picture" or documentation.

Comment: Why not make a submit button that just does a `drupal_goto`, with your query ?

Comment: sure this is an option. But it is a wasted http request with Drupal bootstrap.

Comment: You mean the destination URL is always the form URL ?

Comment: destination url is the form action attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're exactly asking but everything should be well documented on [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7)

I've recently done a form like this so I can give you an example of a GET method form:

```
/**
 * Form function for iwm_collections_search_form block
 */
function mymodule_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#action'] = url(MYMODULE_SEARCH_PATH);
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $form['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('form-main'));
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_search_form_after_build';
  $form['query'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Keywords'),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#size' => 30,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => '',
    '#value' => '',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'submit',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

You need an `#after_build` function to remove the unnecessary hidden fields so that it doesn't clutter the address bar:

```
/**
 * After build callback for mymodule_search_form
 */
function mymodule_search_form_after_build($form) {
  unset($form['form_token']);
  unset($form['form_build_id']);
  unset($form['form_id']);
  return $form;
}
```

No javascript, no submit handlers, easy.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose the form still goes into the $_SESSION, does it? Not a big problem, but it feels wrong.. (not saying this is your fault, maybe this is the only way)

Comment: You drink the water... you follow the rules :) If you want to use Form API then you gotta accept the rules

Comment: Ok so this means there is no API in Drupal that is "designed" for this kind of thing.

Comment: I think it's designed this way to keep it secure from various injections and tampering with the form. Not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to build a submit function that simply does a `drupal_goto`, you can set a dummy submit button and **with Javascript**, *preventDefault* its action, and then do whatever you want as a query.

Comment: This sounds more like a workaround, and requires javascript. Not a bad answer, but there might be better ways.